# Download web page html source after being processed by javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-scraping, phantomjs

I was trying to scrap a page so i downloaded the html source code but then i found that most of the links leading to images and other stuff doesn't appear in the code so i inspect in chrome and found the links

I searched alot for this topic and found phantomjs but it is deprecated now so is there any alternative

Comment: You probably want to scrape using an automation application that embeds Chromium or a javascript engine into itself.

Comment: Currently i am learning CLI commands and bash so i do want to do it myself

Comment: You need a JavaScript engine and probably HTML renderer to interpret pages with dynamic content.   You can slowly and painfully become a human JavaScript interpreter but that means fetching the referenced JS files and then working through the JS and jQuery code to see what it does.  That can be a lot of work, especially if it's minified and possibly obfuscated.  Looking at Chrome's F12 developer tools and the network tab will show you some of what's happening, but things like  XmlHttpRequest often contains nonce / one-time-tokens / parameters that change with every session and/or refresh

Comment: Is there any example of that. I would rather it be as easy as wget as i am not looking forward to learning javascript right now

Comment: You'll need to search for blogs, etc. on scraping web pages if you do not want to use an existing application or framework. Web pages can use any code they want so there is no one answer for scraping all pages.

Comment: Ok. Thanks I will keep searching